# .net DataContractSerializer: how to handle recursive data structures?

Tags: .net, recursion, serialization, data-structures, datacontractserializer

If I have a class with a recursive data structure like this

```
  public class Test
  {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Test Recursion { get; set; }
  }
```

and serialize it

```
     var objectToSave= new Test{Name="Parent"};
     objectToSave.Recursion = test; // this is an endless recursion

     DataContractSerializer ds = new DataContractSerializer(objectToSave.GetType());

     XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
     using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create("result.xml", settings))
        ds.WriteObject(w, objectToSave);
```

i get

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <MyNamespace.Test ...>
      <Name>Parent</Name>
      <Recursion>
        <Name>Parent</Name>
        <Recursion>
          <Name>Parent</Name>
          <Recursion>
            <Name>Parent</Name>
            <Recursion>
           ...... togehter 1586 lines
```

update:
There is a parameter MaxItemsInObjectGraph to limit the output.

Does anybody know how to find out a good value for this?

Or is there a way to tell the serializer how deep recursion should go or to get a more compact xml without redundance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this setting seems to work

```
     DataContractSerializer ds = new DataContractSerializer(objectToSave.GetType(), 
                                     null, 20000, true, true, null);
```

Result

```
    <MyNamespace.Test ...>
      <Name z:Id="2">Parent</Name>
      <Recursion z:Ref="1" i:nil="true" />
    </MyNamespace.Test>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="n" />
```

to define how deep serialization can go. But this will throw exception if you have higher recursion.